# counting the number of iterations of a recursive function in C

Tags: c, recursion

I've been trying to write a recursive function that scans a series of numbers and returns the sum of the numbers in odd indexes minus the sum of numbers in even indexes.

biggest problems: **the function is not supposed to receive any parameters when called upon; and I have to do it in one function.**

**Edit: so, I wrote this code and it seems to work for the most part, but the problem is I wasn't supposed to send any parameters with  the function (`f` wasn't supposed to exist)**

```
void Ex1()  // this is sort of like the main
{
    int f = 1, res;
    res = sumofodd_even(f);
    printf("sum is: %d\n", res-1);
}
```

```
int sumofodd_even(int flag)
{
    int num = 0;
    printf("enter a number. to stop enter -1 >> \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);
    if (num != -1)
    {
        if (flag == -1)
            num *= -1;
        return num + sumofodd_even((-1) * flag);
    }
}
```

btw: can't use pointers or arrays...

will appreciate any help.

Comment: `int sumofodd_even(int counter) { ... /*recurse*/sumofodd_even(counter + 1); ... }`

Comment: I'm lost. Do you want to know the number of *iterations* in this function, or the number of *recursive calls* in a function you chose not to show us?

Comment: I'm trying to write a function similar to this in recursive.
I didn't post what I got so far because it's not much, just trying things out...

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to just use a boolean flag that gets flipped at every recursion:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sumofodd_even(const bool odd) {
    printf("enter a number. to stop enter -1 >> ");
    
    int num = 0;
    scanf("%d", &num);
   
    if (num == -1) {
        return 0; // breaks the recursion
    }

    num *= odd ? 1 : -1;
    
    return num + sumofodd_even(!odd);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("sum is: %d\n", sumofodd_even(false)); // zero is even, thus we start with odd == false

    return 0;
}
```

you can use `odd` to mark if the read value should be treated as an `odd` number or as an even number, and thus change its sign accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the response! 
though the problem is the function is not supposed to receive any parameters when called upon.

Comment: There are zero meaningful reasons for the function to not have any parameters, because you may always have a different `int do_stuff(void)` that just returns `sumofodd_even(false)`. _nota bene_: C is different than C++, and specifying `T func()` actually indicates "an arbitrary number of parameters" instead of "no parameters", for which you are supposed to use `T func(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to counting iterations or flipping a flag is to simply use two functions. After all, your algorithm has two states: process an even-indexed number, or process an odd-indexed number. Rather than have one function with an if statement, just use a function for each state, and have those functions transition between states by calling on each other.

```
int sum_of_odd() {
    // <Ask user for input>
    if (num == -1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return sum_of_even() + num;
}

int sum_of_even() {
    // <Ask user for input>
    if (num == -1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return sum_of_odd() - num;
}
```

And of course you'd start the algorithm by calling sum_of_odd(), since the first number is odd-indexed (unless you want to "index by zero").